# NgRx Perform Action (asynchronously) After Dispatching Action

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

*Note that this question is a clarification question*

## What I Need To Do

I am trying to dispatch an action to NgRx that will add a task to a list of tasks. After this, I need to make a `put` request to an API to store the new changes. The problem, is that I need to do this asynchronously, but `this.store.dispatch(...)` returns `void`. I have a feeling this might be where effects come in handy, but my questions are: is there a better way to do it and is effects the 'right' way. The code below just describes what I am doing currently. The problem with how it works is that the user should click a button, which calls this function with the appropriate parameters, but then the `put` request happens before `this.store.dispatch(...)` finishes, so it only records previously recorded changes, and not what it should be. The other way I could think of doing this is to reconstruct `this.project` within the `projectService.putProject(...)` call with the new changes. Which way is best? I realize this is probably a pretty ignorant question, so sorry.

## The Code

```ts
createNew(title: string, description: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(
      AddTask({
        payload: {
          title: title,
          description: description,
          projectIndex: this.index,
        },
      })
    );
    this.projectService.putProject(this.project).subscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, effects are the best place to put this logic imho.
You could also listen for actions in the component itself (by using `ActionsSubject`), but then you're basically writing your own effect, and you have to deal with the subscription yourself. See https://github.com/typebytes/angular-checklist/blob/3a6cf03d06b3e872d92069856c87678bcd6b21c7/src/app/checklist/search/search.service.ts#L26-L32 for an example.

Comment: Given that I need to have the success or error call another service afterwards (to create a status message the user can user using [ng-bootstrap toast](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/overview#toast-service)), would there be any way to not have an action for success, and error for every Effect? (As that would add a lot of actions). Thank you by the way.

Comment: Having actions that trigger other effects is what I see (and do) the most, but you can also chain service calls inside one effect.